# Intertwine 0s betweeen bits SystemVerilog

Tags: system-verilog, bitmask

I want to intertwine 0s between the bits of a variable. For example, imagine I have a variable `a` as follows

```
a = 1101
```

Then, I want to obtain the following result

```
b = 1_000000_1_000000_0_000000_1
```

That results from intertwining 6 0s betwen each bit of `a`. I was wondering if there was any elegant way of doing this in SystemVerilog. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
b = 0;
foreach (a[i]) b[i*7] = a[i];
```